# Casting CONTEXT_INFO to varchar and the resulting length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, varchar, varbinary, context-info

I'm trying to use `CONTEXT_INFO` to pass a usercode from a stored procedure into a DELETE trigger for table auditing purposes.

It all works fine, however I noticed that the length of the usercode saved in the audit table was not correct.

Take this script as an example...

```
declare @userCode varchar(50)
set @userCode = 'TestUser'

declare @binary_userCode varbinary(128)
set @binary_userCode = cast(@userCode as varbinary(128))
set CONTEXT_INFO @binary_userCode

declare @temp_userCode varchar(50)
set @temp_userCode = (select cast(CONTEXT_INFO() as varchar(50)))

--set @temp_userCode = rtrim(ltrim(@temp_userCode))

select @userCode, len(@userCode), @temp_userCode, len(@temp_userCode)

set CONTEXT_INFO 0x
```

**Results:**

len(@userCode) = 8

len(@temp_userCode) = 50

Why is the `@temp_userCode` variable coming back with a length of 50, and how can I trim it back to it's original length to store it correctly?

***Further Information:***

Running SQL Server 2005, however the solution needs to work in all versions 2005 onwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When assigned to `CONTEXT_INFO` it gets padded out with null bytes `0x00` to 128 bytes in length and becomes `0x5465737455736572000000...`

You can use

```
REPLACE(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS varchar(128)) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN , 
        0x00, 
        '')
```

Comment: This works however I had to change the collation to SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN. This was based on trial and error however which doesn't leave me with much confidence. How can I clarify which collation I should be using?

Comment: @Poz - You didn't state SQL Server version in your question. If previous to 2008 the `100` collations won't be available.

Comment: Apologies. I'm running 2005, however it needs to be suitable for all versions above that too.

Comment: @Poz - Well I'd just use whatever the `BIN` version is of your current default collation. BTW: What is your database's current default collation? Wondering if that is why Aaron's answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: So `Latin1_General_BIN` would be the `BIN` version of that.

Answer (score 4):

It gets padded with `CHAR(0)`. Try:

```
set @temp_userCode = REPLACE(@temp_userCode COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, CHAR(0), '');
```

(**EDIT**: added an explicit `COLLATE` clause, though now I feel like I'm stealing from Martin.)

Comment: +1 I use an explicit cast and collate clause in my answer [because of this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/708179/indefinite-hang-with-replace-statement-on-varbinary-max) but it only appeared for `varbinary(max)` anyway.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, the length is still 50. Due to SQL 2005 perhaps?

Comment: Actually I found two - one running 9.00.3042, the other 9.00.4211, and it worked - both lengths show 8.

Comment: I'm running 9.00.5000.00 with collation Latin1_General_CI_AS. My script is the same as in my question with your line added directly under the "set @temp_userCode" statement.

Comment: Try adding an explicit `COLLATE`. When I use `Latin1_General_CI_AS` explicitly it doesn't work (my test database is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for me on SQL Server 2005:

```
select cast(substring(CONTEXT_INFO(), 1, charindex(0x00, CONTEXT_INFO())-1) as varchar(128));
```

No messy collations to consider :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace will randomly fail on different installations of SQL server [unless you specify the collation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862(v=sql.110).aspx):

```
REPLACE(CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS varchar(128)) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN , 0x00, '')
```

SQL server has two different behaviors, depending on how it is installed:

- Replacement is successful when SQL collation is used.
- Replacement is unsuccessful when Windows collation is used.

This behaviour was submitted to Microsoft nearly over 7 years ago:

> **Q:** When trying a replace a NUL character
>   with replace(), this works is the
>   value has an SQL collation, but not a
>   Windows collation.
>
> **A:** This is due to the fact that 0x0000
>   is an undefined character in Windows
>   collations. All undefined characters
>   are ignored during comparison, sort,
>   and pattern matching. So searching for
>   'a' + char(0) is really searching for
>   ‘a’, and searching for char(0) is
>   equivalent to empty string.
>
> The way to handle undefined character
>   is a bit confusing, but this is the
>   way that Windows defined to sort them,
>   and SQL Server conforms with the
>   general Windows API.
>
> In SQL collation, there is no notion
>   of undefined character. Each code
>   point is assigned a weight, that's why
>   we don't see a problem there.